# How rot13 on a string using PHP?

Tags: php, decode, encode, rot13

I have a big php code that i want to encode and decode it manually.
My problem is that php code has many single quotes and double quotes inside and because of them i have errors while using `str_rot13()` function like below...
So what is the correct syntax and how can I use the function below for encode:

```
str_rot13 ('That php Code');
```

And how can i decode that encoded file? I couldn't find a reverse function!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The nice thing about rot13 is that it's reflective. applying rot 13 twice (e.g. rot 26) brings you right back to where you came from.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer / now what can i do about single and double quotes?

Comment: Non-alpha characters are untouched

Comment: No. gzinflate() will only undo gzdeflate(). inflating twice will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Rot 13 is only designed to handle the 26 characters of the standard English alphabet. If you need more characters, you might want to have a look at ROT47 which is briefly explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT-47)

Comment: hmm that's a trickier problem ... the thing is that you would have to escape all the characters like " ' / in your input with a / so this is a [string](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php) problem am i right?... when you do the decoding this should work fine

Comment: yes, i think it is string problem. but is there a way without changing that string(mean php code). when i replaced " with /" my editor replaced 8956 characters. so i think doing this is not a good idae!

Comment: and it is a backslash to escape caracters in strings not the foreslash I explained earlier my mistake ;-S
and to what if stated above you are still screwed when it comes to double quotes since they already breake your code in advance ... (before you can execute a function)

Comment: Not a problem; English spelling is a weird thing. :)