# How do I hash the password?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm making custom registration form in laravel. When I submit this, in database the password is not being hashed. How do I hash the following password?

```
<div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
            {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password', 'required' => 'true']) }}
        </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing#basic-usage ?

Comment: show us your post logic

Comment: The boilerplate `RegisterController` uses `bcrypt($data['password'])` (where `$data['password']` is presumably the password

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: [ROT-13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10653981/608639) is one of the oldest go-to methods. It is also reversible so you can use it for other services your site offers. A single account can be used everywhere. It is a poor man's Single Sign-On.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have at look at the Docs over [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing).

You can just use the `hash()` function.

```
Hash::make($request->password)
```

Then you got a laravel conform hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok..choose.. many way to use..

1. `Hash::make($password);`
2. `bcrypt($password);`
3. `md5($password);`
4. `sha1($password);`

Answer (score 0):

Worked with

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value){
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }
```